# Barcode scanner library for android other than zxing

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

Is there any open source barcode reader library other than zxing in android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [ZBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/). They have released their [Android SDK](http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/news/) (v0.1)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. Implemented it and feel its more fast and accurate than zxing.